# Remove the "addition" tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

There is no conceivable reason [addition](/questions/tagged/addition) should exist. Barely anyone uses it, it doesn't have any followers, and really what kind of useful information could the tag "addition" possibly convey?

Comment: Just make it a synonym of [jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/48195/172958).

Comment: @Kevin, Could you tell me How [tag:addition] is synonym of [tag:jquery]?

Comment: OK, now I get it :P