# The [add], [adding] and [addition] tags should be cleaned up

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

[add](/questions/tagged/add) and [adding](/questions/tagged/adding) are a complete mess: questions with those tags could be about numeric addition, or adding graphic elements to a screen, new records to a table or modules to software, etc, even though [the wiki for](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/add/info) [add](/questions/tagged/add) describes the tag as being about numeric addition.

I think [addition](/questions/tagged/addition) could hijack that wiki and be used for questions about the addition operation applied to [numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6093534/422353), [arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5394157/422353), [binary numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7334832/422353) and any other [weird object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9350700/422353) that has an equivalent operation. Cleaning those three tags would consolidate that group.

[add](/questions/tagged/add) and [adding](/questions/tagged/adding) could be left as orphaned tags after clean-up or burninated, unless someone has a better idea.

Or we could just wipe them all, of course. ([Someone already suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/153550/172431) that [addition](/questions/tagged/addition) should be burninated but I don't personally agree.)

What do you think?

Comment: add [add] to the burnination list. adding [adding] is also a good idea. I agree with [addition]'s addition too.